# Defining \xthinspace: Thin space only if not followed by certain characters

Tags: spacing, punctuation, xspace

Following [this 2005 thread from the XeTeX list](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2005-November/002778.html), I’ve defined a `\spaceddash` command and assigned it to the Unicode em-dash character U+2014 “—”:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spaceddash}%
    {\unskip\nobreak\thinspace\textemdash\thinspace\ignorespaces}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\spaceddash}

\begin{document}
meow — meow

meow—meow

— meow

meow —.
\end{document}
```

The document this produces looks something like this:

> meow — meow
>   meow — meow
>   — meow
>   meow — .

Notice the thin-space between the em-dash on the last line and the period afterward—I’d like to get rid of it.

Following the example of [xspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace) & [xpunctuate](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpunctuate), I’m trying to define a sort of `\xthinspace` command, one that will insert the `\thinspace` *except* if the dash is followed by certain punctuation marks (*e.g.*, period, comma, close-parenthesis, close-quote).

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a possibility using `expl3`. The test gobbles spaces and then checks whether the following token appears in the exceptions list. If not, it applies `\thinspace`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{newunicodechar,xparse}

% The following is equivalent to \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{...}
\newunicodechar{—}{\spaceddash} % write only `\spaceddash` in aux files
\NewDocumentCommand{\spaceddash}{%
  \ifvmode\leavevmode\else\unskip\nobreak\thinspace\fi
  \textemdash\xthinspace}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xthinspace}{ } { \xths_main: }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtoxthinspaceexceptions}{m}
 {
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_xths_exceptions_tl { #1 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xths_main:
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l_xths_apply_bool
  \peek_catcode_ignore_spaces:NF \c_space_token { \xths_check: }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xths_check:
 {
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \g_xths_exceptions_tl
    {
     \token_if_eq_charcode:NNT ##1 \l_peek_token
      {\bool_set_false:N \l_xths_apply_bool \prg_map_break: }
    }
  \bool_if:NT \l_xths_apply_bool { \thinspace }
 }
\tl_new:N \g_xths_exceptions_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addtoxthinspaceexceptions{,.)}

\begin{document}
meow—meow

meow—.

meow— .
\end{document}
```

Try it with `\hspace{1cm}` instead of `\thinspace` if you want to verify it works. A limitation: if the — is followed by a macro that *expands* to a comma, a period or a closed parenthesis, the test will fail.

Comment: Definition of `\spaceddash` is missing the argument specifier, also the `\unskip\nobreak` & `\ignorespaces`; but with those changes, this does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Also, `\kern1em` is more appropriate than `\hspace` for testing, because it won’t leave space at line’s beginning (`\thinspace` is just `\kern.1666em`) (though it plays funny games with vertical kerning at the start of a paragraph). After defining `\dashspace` to `\kern1em` (for testing) or `\thinspace`, my definition was `\NewDocumentCommand{\spaceddash}{ }{\unskip\nobreak\ifhmode\dashspace\fi\textemdash\xthinspace\ignorespaces}`

Comment: @J.C.Salomon I've added the test for vertical mode; `\xthinspace\ignorespaces` is an error, as `\xthinspace` has `\ignorespaces` after it and so the test it performs is useless.

Answer (score 8):

`\@ifnextchar` (thanks @egreg) is your friend here:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spaceddash}%
    {\unskip\nobreak\thinspace\textemdash\gobblespaces}
\makeatletter\def\gobblespaces{\@ifnextchar.\relax\thinspace}\makeatother
```

\@ifnextchar gobbles any intervening space tokens. It compares the first non-space token
found to its first argument ("`.`" here) and executes the first macro if they are the same ("`\relax'"); otherwise, it executes the second macro ("`\thinspace'").

Obviously, this could be generalized to look for any number of tokens. I'm sure `xspace` does something similar.

A full MWE is:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\spaceddash}%
    {\unskip\nobreak\thinspace\textemdash\gobblespaces}
\makeatletter\def\gobblespaces{\@ifnextchar.\relax\thinspace}\makeatother
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\spaceddash}

\begin{document}
meow — meow

meow—meow

— meow

meow —.
\end{document}
```

And the resulting document looks like:

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a spacing issue on the right for the first and third case.