# Defining a command to define commands where the name uses the argument using xparse

Tags: xparse

Using `xparse` I want to create a command which defines other commands. However I want the secondary command to consist of text and then the argument to the first command. For example

For example in the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\DeclareTest}{m}{%
%
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\csname test#1\endcsname}{}{This is a #1 test}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareTest{work}
\testwork

\end{document}
```

I would like `\testwork` to be a command that evaluates to `This is a work test`. However when I do this I get an `"xparse/bad-arg-spec"` error and I am not sure why.

Comment: Related is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63568/newdocumentcommand-with-constructed-csname, but perhaps that one is rather specialised so not a dupe as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is the case for `\newcommand`, `\DeclareDocumentCommand` and relatives are designed to take ta command *name* as the first argument. At present, if you want to construct the name you therefore need to use `\expandafter`

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\DeclareTest{m}{%
  \expandafter\DeclareDocumentCommand\csname test#1\endcsname{}{This is a test}%
}
```

The reason that at the moment there is not a 'variant' available which does this internally is that 'dynamic' commands are problematic from a conceptual point of view. The syntax of `xparse` is intended to make it clear within the code what new commands are begin created for a document, and thus constructing them 'on the fly' is really not what the aim is. This is however I think still and area which needs discussion based on good examples from real use cases.

Comment: I just run into a similar problem. I want to create some commands on the fly *with optional arguments*.   With `\cs_set:c...` is is easy to handle the names, but the optional arguments are difficult, with xparse the arguments are easy but the name needs `\expandafter`.